# Cognos Analytics 11.1.6 - Reports Requesting User ID and Password When Clicked

Tags: login, user-accounts, reporting, prompt, cognos

I'm running **Cognos Analytics 11.1.6** and restored a bunch of reports from the previous server that was running **10.2.2**. A user mentioned that when she **clicks a report** on the 11 instance **she is required to enter a user id and password for the data source** in order to view/run the report which is not ideal. I don't want to be sharing out sql account information to users.

In the **admin console** the data source this specific report is using has a '**signon**' configured with a local sql account that connects to the necessary sql server. If I test the connection it comes back successful. Can somebody please explain/assist on what I need to do in order to **prevent the user id / password prompt from appearing** **when users run Cognos reports**?

I have very limited Cognos experience and IBM's documentation is lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of now it looks like the solution for my problem was changing the data source connection from 'other type' to 'sql server native client'. After the change my client stopped receiving login prompts.